# Proving $ a^4 \equiv 1 \pmod d$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I need to prove the following statements:

Prove the following statements:

(a) if $a$ is odd then $a^4 ≡ 1 \pmod 4$,

(b) if $5$ does not divide a, then $a^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$.

Can I do this inductively? Or should I be adopting another approach? I know for (a), if $a$ is odd, $a^4$ will also be odd, as the product of odd numbers is always odd. This would mean that $4 \mid (a^4 - 1)$, which would always be an even number, but of course not all even numbers are divisible by 4 (or rather $(a^4 - 1)$ would always be an even number). I also know you can obtain all the congruence cases of $1 \pmod 5$ by adding or subtracting $5$, beginning at $1$.

Comment: For (a), see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827165/prove-that-for-all-odd-integer-n-n4-1-pmod-16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**
a) If $a$ is odd, then $a$ is of the form $2k+1.$ So expand $a^2.$
b) If $5\not\mid a,$ then $a$ is congruent modulo $5$ to one of $1,2,3,4,$ so you can enumerate these four cases.
Also, have a look at [Euler's theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/Euler.shtml), or just [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I think I see it now. 4k^2 + 4k + 1 is obviously divisible by 4 (after you expand out a^2), right?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant to say. :)

Comment: @ChrisT $4k^2+4k+1$ is *obviously* not divisible by $4$.....$(4k^2+4k+1)-1$ is divisible...

Comment: @tatan Thanks for pointing this slip of *eyes* out. :) BTW, why do you tag $4k^2+4k+1?$ It isn't a user's name, is it?

Comment: @awllower It's my slip...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For the first $(2n+1)^4=1+4m$

For the second, compute $1^4,2^4,3^4,4^4 \pmod 5$

Answer (score 2):

Since the moduli are small, you can simply go through all the cases:

**1.** If $a$ is odd, then $a \equiv 1$ or $3 \pmod 4$.
$$1^4 = 1 \pmod 4$$
$$3^4 = \ldots \equiv 1 \pmod 4$$

**2.** If $5$ does not divide $a$, then $a \equiv 1,2,3$ or $4 \pmod 5$.
$$1^4 = 1 \pmod 5$$
$$2^4 = \ldots \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
$$\text{etc.}$$

Comment: I was thinking of just demonstrating cases for a, is that usually sufficient to prove the claim?

Comment: @ChrisT Yes, and that is the gist of my answer. It is sufficient, so long as you cover all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

> If $a$ is odd, then $a^4\equiv1\pmod4$:

- $a\equiv\color\red1\pmod4 \implies a^4\equiv\color\red1^4\equiv1\pmod4$
- $a\equiv\color\red3\pmod4 \implies a^4\equiv\color\red3^4\equiv81\equiv1\pmod4$

---

> If $5$ does not divide $a$, then $a^4\equiv1\pmod5$:

- $a\equiv\color\red1\pmod5 \implies a^4\equiv\color\red1^4\equiv1\pmod5$
- $a\equiv\color\red2\pmod5 \implies a^4\equiv\color\red2^4\equiv16\equiv1\pmod5$
- $a\equiv\color\red3\pmod5 \implies a^4\equiv\color\red3^4\equiv81\equiv1\pmod5$
- $a\equiv\color\red4\pmod5 \implies a^4\equiv\color\red4^4\equiv256\equiv1\pmod5$